# Android Card View ripple effect starts right after a click

Tags: android, android-cardview

I have a simple card view list. When clicking a card, I set a ripple effect:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="170dp"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:orientation="horizontal"
card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"

card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
```

It seems like the ripple effect starts right after I click on a card.
So the ripple effect happens most of the times I just click on the card in order to scroll it. This is an annoying behavior.

Is there a way of "delaying" the ripple effect or making it happen only on a real click and not also on a scroll?

Comment: Are you talking about the default behavior that happens on every view? If you hold your finger in place during the beginning of the scroll, Android detects a DOWN event and starts the ripple. If you start your scroll quicker, the ripple does not show up.

Comment: I beleive I am talking about the default behavior. I seems this behavior is not so pleasent. Any way of changing it?

Comment: I disagree that it is "not pleasant" because it is the standard interaction across the entire OS. If you really want to change it this is a great place to start: http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html.

Comment: I am not sure this is standard interaction. I do not see the same behavior on other apps. The delay before showing the ripple effect seems to be longer and less anoying.

Answer (score 2):

Set `android:clickable="true"` in card view.